# SignalR send data Page loading

Tags: load, signals

im getting a prblem when i want to send data o start a sub from hub when the page is loading. ill put this sample code because is short

this is my chat.vb

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.Collections.Generic
 Imports System.Linq
 Imports System.Web
 Imports SignalR.Hubs

 Public Class Chat
    Inherits Hub
    Public Sub Send(message As String)
       ' Call the addMessage method on all clients
        Clients.addMessage(message)
    End Sub
 End Class
```

and this is my default.aspx

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly
        var chat = $.connection.chat;

        // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
        chat.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
        };

        $("#broadcast").click(function () {
           // Call the chat method on the server
           chat.send($('#msg').val());
       }); 
       // Start the connection
       $.connection.hub.start();
    });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%">
     <input type="text" id="msg" />
     <input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" /> 
     <ul id="messages">
     </ul>
   </div> 
   </form>
 </body>
```

i dont want to press the button, i want he doit all by itself when loads the page

when i put it like this

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly
        var chat = $.connection.chat;

        // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
        chat.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
        }; 

       chat.send('Hello World');

       // Start the connection
       $.connection.hub.start();
    });
 </script>
```

i got an connection problem
i get this error  "SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call start before you do send.

So:

```
chat.send('Hello World');

// Start the connection
$.connection.hub.start();
```

SHOULD BE:

```
// Start the connection
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    // Call the server side function AFTER the connection has been started
    chat.send('Hello World');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I DO IT, i have to delete the function and leave it without it just like this

<script type="text/javascript">  
        var chat = $.connection.chat; invoke it
        chat.addMessage = function (message) {
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
        }; 
        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            //alert('Hello World');
                chat.send('Hello World'); 
        }); 
</script>, but i have to call it from outside of any function because inside of them not works. thanks